# Why is this force in the $\hat{z}$ direction - magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vectors

So this picture is in my lecture notes, but I simply cannot see how this force is in the $\hat{z}$ direction?

The $d\vec{l}$ section is in the $- (x-y)$ plane and when you cross it with the magnetic field in the $x$ plane, you can't just end up with something in the $\hat{z}$ direction, can you?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK1ZO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\vect}[1]{{\bf #1}}$
$\newcommand{\uvect}[1]{\hat{\bf #1}}$
As you point out, on the segment connecting the point 1 and 2, the line differential $dl$ lies on the plane $xy$,

$$
d\vect{l}  = dl_x~\uvect{x} + dl_y~\uvect{y}
$$

therefore,

$$
d\vect{l}\times\vect{B} \sim (dl_x~\uvect{x} + dl_y~\uvect{y})\times (B~\uvect{x}) = Bdl_y(\uvect{y}\times\uvect{x}) \sim \uvect{z}
$$